# Using function arguments in update.formula

Tags: r

I am writing a function that takes two variables and separately regresses each of them on a set of controls expressed as a one-sided formula. Right now I'm using the following to make the formula for one of the regressions, but it feels a bit hacked-up:

```
foo <- function(x, y, controls) {
    cl <- match.call()
    xn <- cl[["x"]]
    xf <- as.formula(paste(xn, deparse(controls)))
}
```

I'd prefer to do this using `update.formula()`, but of course `update.formula(controls, x ~ .)` and `update.formula(controls, as.name(x) ~ .)` don't work. What should I be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
right <- ~ a + b + c
left <- ~ y 
left_2 <- substitute(left ~ ., list(left = left[[2]]))

update(right, left_2)
```

But I think you'll have to either paste text strings together, or use substitute.  To the best of my knowledge, there are no functions to create one two sided formula from two one-sided formulas (or similar equivalents).

Comment: I wonder if there is a better answer eight years later, based on quosures or the rlang package in general?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about `update.formula()`, but I have used the approach you take here of pasting text and converting it via `as.formula` in the past with success.  My reading of `help(update.formula)` does not make me think you can substitute the left-hand side as you desire.

Lastly, trust the dispatching mechanism.  If you object is of type formula, just call `update` which is preferred over the explicit `update.formula`.